Javascript Dynamics CRM - prevent save
I have the below script which successfully validates if there are child projects at the same level as the current project on the form and gives the dialogue if the validation fails. What I want to do is prevent the form from saving if the validation fails but allow it to save if the validation is ok. I keep going round in circles and not managing to get anywhere, any help would be massively appreciated
//On Save validation
varProjectMainForm = (function () {
  "use strict";

var SaveMode = {
    Save: 1,
    SaveAndClose: 2,
    SaveAndNew: 59,
    Autosave: 70
};

var saveMode;

var hasCheckedConflict = false;

function OnSave(executionContext) {
    
     //preventing of the save operation before async operation is started
    var eventArgs = executionContext.getEventArgs();
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
    
/*  if (!hasCheckedConflict)
    {
    executionContext.getEventArgs().preventDefault();
    }
    else
    {
    formContext.data.entity.save()
    } */
    
    saveMode = executionContext.getEventArgs().getSaveMode();
    
    // Specific validation for existing records (not new)
    if (formContext.ui.getFormType() === 2) {
    if (!hasCheckedConflict) {
      hasCheckedConflict = true;
      fetchChildrenProjects(formContext, eventArgs);
    }
    } else {
        console.log("Skipping execution for new records");  // Log for new records, no validation needed
    }

/*     if (eventArgs.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        return;  // No further validation is required if default save has been prevented
    } */

    //saveMode = eventArgs.getSaveMode();
    if (![SaveMode.Save, SaveMode.SaveAndClose, SaveMode.SaveAndNew, SaveMode.Autosave].includes(saveMode)) {
        return;  // Exit if the save mode is not one of the expected modes
    }

}

function fetchChildrenProjects(formContext, eventArgs) {
    var projectID = formContext.getAttribute("dmis_dmisid").getValue();
    var projectLevel = formContext.getAttribute("dmis_displaylevel").getValue();
    


    var fetchXML = "<fetch top='1'>" +
        "<entity name='dmis_dmishierarchy'>" +
        "<attribute name='dmis_dmishierarchyid'/>" +
        "<filter>" +
        "<condition attribute='dmis_dmisid' operator='eq' value='" + projectID + "'/>" +
        "</filter>" +
        "</entity>" +
        "</fetch>";

    var encodedFetchXML = encodeURIComponent(fetchXML);
    Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("dmis_dmishierarchy", "?fetchXml=" + encodedFetchXML).then(
        function success(result) {
            if (result.entities.length > 0) {
                var hierarchyId = result.entities[0].dmis_dmishierarchyid;
                checkForConflict(formContext, projectLevel, hierarchyId, eventArgs);
            } else {
                console.log("No children projects found for: " + projectID);
               // eventArgs.preventDefault();
            }
        },
        function (error) {
            Xrm.Navigation.openAlertDialog({ text: "Error retrieving hierarchy ID: " + error.message });
           // eventArgs.preventDefault();
        }
    );
}

function checkForConflict(formContext, projectLevel, hierarchyId, eventArgs) {
    
    
    var fetchXML = "<fetch>" +
        "<entity name='dmis_dmishierarchy'>" +
        "<attribute name='dmis_displaylevel'/>" +
        "<filter>" +
        "<condition attribute='dmis_parent' operator='eq' value='" + hierarchyId + "'/>" +
        "</filter>" +
        "</entity>" +
        "</fetch>";

    var encodedFetchXML = encodeURIComponent(fetchXML);
    Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("dmis_dmishierarchy", "?fetchXml=" + encodedFetchXML).then(
        function success(result) {
            if (result.entities.some(entity => entity.dmis_displaylevel <= projectLevel)) {
                Xrm.Navigation.openAlertDialog({
                     title: "Save Conflict",
                    text:"Cannot save due to this object having children at or below this display level."
                })
                hasCheckedConflict = true;
            } else {
          //There's no issue, allow saving

          //and save event is called again
          if (saveMode === SaveMode.Save || saveMode === SaveMode.Autosave) {
            formContext.data.entity.save();
            hasCheckedConflict = true;
          } else if (saveMode === SaveMode.SaveAndClose) {
            formContext.data.entity.save("saveandclose");
          } else {
            formContext.data.entity.save("saveandnew");
          }
        } 
        },
        function (error) {
            Xrm.Navigation.openAlertDialog({ text: "Error checking for conflicts: " + error.message });
            eventArgs.preventDefault();  // Error occurred, prevent save
        }
    );
}

return {
    OnSave: OnSave
};
})();


I've tried adding validation checks and updating a global variable, nothing seems to work. the validation does work with prevent default off but as soon as I add executionContext.getEventArgs().preventDefault(); it wont save any record

In your code is not clear how the "onSave" function is attached to the form's submit action. If you want to prevent the form from saving you have to return false;, not only return;, and also preferibly, execute event.preventDefault() if you have access to the event object. Also another option is just to use a regular button (not a submit button) and call the form.submit() manually when all validations pass.

really appreciate you taking the time to answer. this is a javascript web resource in a model driven app so not connected to any buttons, just using the OnSave event

Maybe check that the Model Driven App has the Async save handler enabled.
Also note that async save handler has a 10 sec time out. You might want to check how long that process checks are taking and making sure you maybe wrap the multiple web api calls in a Promise.all() method.
I assume you've already looked at the docs but here's the link to the OnSave Event

Personally seeing what you're doing in the JS with the fetchxml queries and then comparing/checking conflicts...I would use a custom plugin on Pre-Validation and that in the end the plugin would just handle the logical check and if it isn't valid it just won't save it at all.
Hope this helps! :)
